# apache2 wordpress disallow / forbid access to folder from .htaccess in root folder -> RedirectMatch not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hello I want to use the `.htaccess` file in the root folder of the wordpress installtion to disallow access to the files in the subfolder `wp-snapshots`.

My content of the file `/srv/www/vhosts/website1/.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
RedirectMatch 403 ^/wp-snapshots/?$
```

But if I access with a web browser the following file `/srv/www/vhosts/website1/wp-snapshots/test.txt` I can still access the content.

- Having a .htaccess file in the `wp-snapshots` is NOT an option
- Alias apache2 module is activated:

  apache2ctl -M | grep alias
  alias_module (shared)

I am happy to hear also other options to forbid the access to the folder with using the root `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

I’d use a RewriteRule instead (assuming you have mod_rewrite available as well.)

```
RewriteRule ^wp-snapshots - [F]
```

- match every request URL path that starts with `wp-snapshots` (no leading slash, that has already been stripped off at that point, when configuring rewriting in .htaccess),
- do no actual rewriting (`-`), and
- respond with a 403 Forbidden (`[F]` flag)